# how to stop my own broadcast message？

Tags: c, networking, udp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ignore your own broadcast udp packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762101/how-to-ignore-your-own-broadcast-udp-packets)

I am trying to broadcast a discovery message through UDP that discovers all other people in the same subnet. but as soon as I am also in the subnet, I will then receive this message too.
Is there a way to stop receiving the message that generates by myself?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762101/how-to-ignore-your-own-broadcast-udp-packets

Answer (score 2):

You can **ignore** the message you broadcast yourself, but you can never stop it from reaching you once you sent it out.