# Receive the data without own sent by QUdpSocket

Tags: android, qt, udp

I'm testing a P2P communication by udp with Qt 5.4(on Windows 10 64bit).

On Windows to Windows, this code can get a message("SendFromHost") from an another device. But on Android to Windows, this code got a own sent message("SendFromGuest") and finished the program.

Please tell me how to get a message without own sent.

```
void Network::start()
{
    findLanSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    connect(findLanSocket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),
                this, SLOT(onUdpStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
    findLanSocket->bind(findPort, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);

    QByteArray datagram = "SendFromGuest";
    findLanSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), QHostAddress::Broadcast, findPort);
}

void Network::onUdpStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState s)
{
    if (s == QAbstractSocket::BoundState) {
        connect(findLanSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyUdpRead()));
    }
}

void Network::onReadyUdpRead()
{
    QByteArray datagram; QHostAddress haddr;
    datagram.resize(findLanSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
    findLanSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &haddr);

    QString rev = QString::fromUtf8(datagram);
    if (rev == "SendFromHost"){
        result = haddr.toString();
        qDebug() << result;
        success();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast UDP datagram can also be received by its sender, that's the expected behavior. See [How to ignore your own broadcast udp packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762101/how-to-ignore-your-own-broadcast-udp-packets) for instance.

Comment: Do you know the option parameters for Qt 5?

Comment: I don't think Qt provides an option for that (apart from doing multicast instead of broadcast). For broadcast, you'd have to use one of the trick in the answers I've linked to.

Comment: Note: for me, I'd not use the IP address but insert a unique (internally-generated) ID in the datagram, so that I'm able to identify my own messages (because they contain my ID) and discard them.