# Detecting own message when sending UDP broadcast

Tags: c++, winsock2

My program (C++, winsock, Windows 8, 10) sends UDP broadcast message to invite other computers to make connection via TCP.

Therefore, the program receives this (own) message just like other computers too.

The question is: how can I find out that my program has got **your own** message ?

One way I see is to generate unique number (key), send it with broadcast message, analyze it when the message received – if matches the unique key, then it is own message.

Are there more simple way ?

Comment: Can't you check if it was sent from your IP address?

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to ignore your own broadcast udp packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762101/)