# Raspberry pi only broadcasts on loopback

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi4

I have a class that needs to broadcast its existence over the local network

In the `__init__()`,  I make the following calls:

```
self._interfaces = socket.getaddrinfo(host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port=None, family=socket.AF_INET)
        self._allIps = [ip[-1][0] for ip in self._interfaces]
        self._running = True
```

And in the thread that takes care of sending the broadcast on a loop, I run the following code:

while self._running:

```
        for ip in self._allIps:
            if self._logger:
                self._logger.log("[Client] broadcasting ID", Verbosity.Trace)
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)  # UDP
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
            sock.bind((ip, 0))
            sock.sendto(msg, ("255.255.255.255", 5777))
            sock.close()

        sleep(2)
```

Following the suggestions in this [stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066634/sending-broadcast-in-python)

When I run this on a windows machine it works just fine and there is a valid ip in self._allIps
but When I run this on my raspberry pi self._allIps will be a list containing "127.0.0.1" 3 times

Why does it not return the actual ip of the pi and why don't I get a proper broadcast message over the local network?

Comment: Is there an entry in `/etc/hosts` that matches the value returned by `socket.gethostbyname()`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Bind to `'0.0.0.0'` for “all interfaces”

Answer (score 0):

@MarkTolonen had it right,

i should have bound to "0.0.0.0".
This did the trick and made my pi broacst over the local network